# Is Offset should specify at the end of Sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

1. SELECT * CUSTOMERS LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0.

Assume CUSTOMERS is table of details. The above query works fine but if i specify offset other than end of query i get error.

2. Created a table with following details.

Table name is sms_view
[image]

Query:

SELECT SMS FROM sms_view WHERE read=2 LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0;

Result is

[image]

The above result is expected and it is based on read value. So, the table is created based on read value, offset and limit applied on the created table. so the result is shown above.

But My requirement is, offset and Limit should apply on entire table and read value should apply on created table.

Expected result is:
[image]

I need a query on expected result.

Comment: Where else would you want to put it? `OFFSET` is part of the `LIMIT` clause, which belongs at the end of the query. And it makes hardly any sense without an `ORDER BY` clause by the way.

Comment: And it's missing FROM, so we have different definitions of 'fine'

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should be at the end. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS 
ORDER BY somecolumn  -- important to get consistent results
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

Another way to do the same thing is:

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS 
ORDER BY somecolumn
LIMIT 0, 5
```

or in this case (as the offset is 0):

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS 
ORDER BY somecolumn
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 2):

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> Drop table if exists sms_view;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> create table sms_view(SMS int,db_id int, `read`  int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.28 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into sms_view values
    -> (1, 2, 3) ,
    -> (2, 2, 3),
    -> (3, 2, 2) ,
    -> (4, 2, 2) ,
    -> (5, 2, 2) ,
    -> (6, 2, 2) ,
    -> (7, 2, 2) ,
    -> (8, 2, 2) ,
    -> (9, 2, 2) ,
    -> (10, 2, 2);
Query OK, 10 rows affected (0.04 sec)
Records: 10  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select sms from
    -> (
    -> SELECT * FROM sms_view LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
    -> ) s
    ->  WHERE `read` = 2;
+------+
| sms  |
+------+
|    3 |
|    4 |
|    5 |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: - P.Salmon, the solution provided is specific to expected result scenario. Is there any way to get generic solution

Comment: In what way generic?

Comment: I have a sql query like  (SELECT * FROM table name WHERE filter criteria (read=2) ORDER BY column name) and applying  LIMIT OFFSET values. The full sql query is (SELECT * FROM table name WHERE filter criteria (read=2) ORDER BY column name LIMIT value OFFSET value) The limit and OFFSET values are applying on sql query ( table was created with sql query) in the case if i have LIMIT and OFFSET.

Comment: It sounds like you want to generate a sql statement by passing a bunch of parameters (table name, column list, where statement, limit, offset) -  why would you want to do that doesn't seem worth the bother to me since the parameter list is pretty much the sql statement anyway .